# nextjs 14 - dynamic route js file returns 404 (only in production) - updated with Demo

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using NextJS 14 (the latest version) and I am having an issue with dynamic routes in production

I have a route `/products/[id]`

I have a page.js under `/products/[id]` to load product details

When I access this route, I get following message on screen

```
Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).
```

When I check console I see following message

```
webpack-20fbacf1cd4b3f42.js:1  GET xxxxxxx.com/_next/static/chunks/app/(routes)/(user)/products/%5Bid%5D/page-b639ea77763a04ad.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

This page works perfectly on my local server and on Netlify, but not in production server (Cloudways)

All dynamic routes has this problem and all other pages are working perfectly

UPDATE

I have the source code hosted at

https://github.com/silkcoder/nextjs-demo

I have deployed the application into netlify and Cloudways server

Its working fine on netlify (You can click on a product name and it will show product details page)

https://main--extraordinary-cocada-dfed13.netlify.app/

but issue exits on Cloudways server

https://phpstack-1113030-4098351.cloudwaysapps.com/ click on any product links to view the issue

In cloudways Apache running the server and static files are served by Nginx. The application is running on port 3000 and I have the following .htaccess file to make the site available for the above domain

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://localhost:3000/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:3000/$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: It seems like it was in 13 and fixed later, https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/54008